# Pycharm does not autocomplete methods for class inheriting with aliased import

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I have two python files which define classes, one of these files imports a class as an alias and uses it as the parent of a class.  My issue is that PyCharm does not provide any information on the inherited properties or methods when I use the import alias.

**class_a.py**

```
class A(object):
    def do_something(self, arg):
        print(arg)
```

**class_b.py**

```
from class_a import A as BaseA
class B(BaseA):
    def do_some # I expect pycharm to show autocomplete here because `def do_something(...) exists on the parent class
```

So as I'm typing methods or properties in `class B` it doesn't show any autocomplete as if it has no idea that `BaseA` is actually `A`.  Is this a bug in Pycharm?

Comment: Fascinating, indeed autocomplete doesnt work as it does when simply importing with `from class_a import A`, even though "go to definition" properly identifies `BaseA` as `class A(object)` when hovering with CTRL depressed, and does jump to the definition just fine.

Comment: You could use `Override method` [action](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/overriding-methods-of-a-superclass.html)